# Hosted microservice, SpringSecurityContextProvider : Security context not available

Tags: cumulocity

I developed a microservice using microservice SDK 9.9.0. The microservice is running hosted at Cumulocity and is working fine. I get only many WARN messages in the logging file:

...
2018-08-24 12:44:41.400  WARN 11 --- [http-nio-80-exec-9] .c.m.s.f.p.SpringSecurityContextProvider : Security context not available.
...

What exactly does it mean and has this some negative impact?

Answer (score 0):

The logging is caused by the health check.
The health check is executed without any credentials and therefore spring is logging this statement as it cannot create the security context.

As the health endpoint in the SDK does not require any credentials it is no problem.

You can also raise the log level for this class if the entries are spamming the log file too much.